# Error when trying to get information SOAP from Node.js

Tags: xml, node.js, web-services, api, soap

This is working fine on php but it's not on node.js
I'm getting the following error (I replaced the actual service for clientlink
I'm not a node expert so I don't have any clue where to start on here,
Thanks for everything!!!

> body: '\r\n\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\tsoap:Server\r\n\t\t\tError response (code 500 from
>   clientlink/soap: <soap:Enve lope
>   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soa
>   p:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><fa
>   ultstring>Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element
>   (uri:"clientlink", local:"callerIp").
>   Expec ted elements are
>   &lt;{}enterpriseActorId>,&lt;{}onBelhalfOfId>,&am
>   p;lt;{}externalClientId>,&lt;{}callerIp>,&lt;{}actorId>,&lt
>   ;{}agencyIdLong>,&lt;{}onBehalfOfId>,&lt;{}applicationId>,&
>   lt;{}actionId>,&lt;{}agencyId>
>   </faultstring></soap:Fault>
>   </soap:Body></soap:Envelope>\n\r\n\t\t\r\
>   n\t\r\n' },

The code on node is:

```
var url = 'clientlink';
  var args = {
    "context": {
      "appToken": 'MEGATOKEN'
    },
    "version": 1.0
  };

soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        callback(err);
        return
      }
      client.getEvents(args, function(err, result) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(err);
            return;
          }
          console.log(result);
      });
    });
```

The code on php that is working fine!

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient('clientlink');
$params['context']['appToken'] = 'MEGATOKEN';
$params['version'] =1.0;
$info = $soapClient->__call('getEvents', array($params));
```

Thanks for reading the second thanks!! :)

Comment: Have to put that in: http://nodejsreactions.tumblr.com/post/54266850885/being-told-our-new-node-system-will-need-to-talk-with-a : D

Comment: @dollarVar that gif correlates more to the fact that we had to use mysql instead of mongo ;)

Comment: Yeah, still do not know if *not* having prepared statements is a good thing ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First use `describe()` to see what methods of the remote service are available.

```
//...
soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
  if (err) {
    // ...
  } else {
    client.describe();
  }
});
```

Here is an example of the output from `client.describe()`:

```
{
  MyService: {
    MyPort: {
      getEvents: {
        input: {
          name: 'string'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can call `getEvents()` like this:

```
//...
soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
  if (err) {
    // ...
  } else {
    client.MyService.MyPort.getEvents({name: 'value'}, function(err, result) {
      // ...
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Huge thanks. Never done soap and this saved my life!